# Set different catalog price rules/promotions for each language on a multi-language store

Tags: store-view, promotions, price-rules

I have a magento eccommerce with 3 different languages (3 store views).
Prices are the same in each language/store view (and all in euro), but I would like to apply different catalog discounts for each language, for example 10% discount for italian site, 20% discount for french and 25% for english.
How can I do this?
Do I need to install an extension?

Thanks a lot for your help.

P.S. I'm not a magento specialist, so I hope I can do this without code changes.

Thanks a lot
Carlo

Answer (score 3):

The catalog price rules are on website level, mainly because the price can be on a global or website level. You cannot have different prices and different catalog price rules on the store view level.
An option would be to transform your 3 store view into 3 websites with one store view each.
This should be simple enough.
Just create 2 more websites and associate 2 of the store views to them...one for each.
Then you have to bulk update the products to associate them to all the websites.
You can do that from the product grid, buy selecting all of them and selecting "Change attributes" from the top right select.

Then you will be able to add your discount rules as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You know that Magento default just allows setting up catalog price rule (promotions) at the level of website, which means that all settings are applied for the whole website, including store views.

Therefore, if your store has three store views, it is very difficult for you to do this one. However, if you want to set up shopping cart price rule for each store view of your store, I think there are some extensions that can support you.

You can go to Magento Connect and search for Shopping cart price rule for store view. I had searched and found out some extensions you can read more like:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shopping-cart-rule-per-store-view.html

As I can see, this extension will add an condition "Store view" into creating new rule and then you can choose it to start your setting.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be closely watched, but I have an alternative solution:

1. After creating the new store views, create an attribute like "store_view" to hold values that differ between them. 
   **Make sure that this is set to the Store View scope and Use for Promo Rule Conditions is set to Yes**
2. Set distinct values for all products at each **Store View** level in AMIN->MANAGE PRODUCTS->ACTIONS->UPDATE ATTRIBUTES.
3. Add another condition to your promotion to only apply in the case that a specific value is defined for the store_view, and repeat for each store_view/value.

Answer (score 0):

Add products in different 'Attribute Set' for each store. Then in Catalog Price Rule, under Conditions add this one "Attribute Set  is YOUR_SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTE_SET "