# how to create discounts based on order total?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, catalog-price-rules, promotions

we want to give 5 % of discounts if customer added items with total order value is greater than 1000.

we don't want to apply any coupon codes.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Navigate to **Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules**.

2) Add New Rule.

3) In Rule Information add details like.

[image]

4) Add Condition like.

[image]

4) Action like.

[image]

5) Enter Labels whatever you want and you are done.

6) Your result will be like.

[image]
Hope this will help you.

Comment: i want to give discounts only to one store view. i can't see differnt store views in `websites` textfield, any idea why its missing ?

Comment: have a look on this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25613/set-different-catalog-price-rules-promotions-for-each-language-on-a-multi-langua

Comment: can you come here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40539/chat-with-xtech

Answer (score 1):

You can set the discount from backend Top Navigation `Promotions` >> `Shopping Cart Price Rule` Section.

You need to set Conditions like below screenshot: 
[image]
You need to Actions like below screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: i need to apply coupon code right for getting discount ?

Comment: Thanks for your support. as other answer guide me that we can create shopping cart price rules without using coupon codes also in first image, i am accepting that answer.